# Spectrum of the operator $T \in \mathcal{L}(L^2(\Bbb{R}_+))$ defined by $(Tf)(x)=(1−e^{−x})f(x)$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory, spectra

I'm preparing a mathematical physics exam (the last one) and one of the topic is the spectral theory on operators.
I am totally confused on some concept, so please pardon me.
I am studying this operator $T:\mathcal{L}(L^2(R^+))$ defined by $(Tf)(x)=(1-e^{-x})f(x)$

So I have proved that this operator $T$ is limited because $||Tf||^2< +\infty$ and beign a multiplication operator, $||T|| = 1$. Now I want to find the spectre.

So for this I am confused. I have $\lambda f(x) = T f(x)$ and I want the $f \ne 0$ so I arrive at $f(x)(\lambda -1+e^{-x})=0$.
Here I know that the resolvent $\rho(T) := \{ \lambda \in C:| \lambda|>1 \}$ (out of the spectral radius) and the spectre $\sigma(T)=C/ \rho(T) $.
How can I find if there is punctual, continous and residual spectra of this operator? I wish to have some guidelines and explanation because I am very confused, and also I do not have so much time for study since I work too.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your operator is self-adjoint in Hilbert space, therefore, from theory follows that it's residual spectrum is empty. Moreover, his spectrum is real. Point spectrum also empty, because from the equation $(1-e^{-x})f(x)=\lambda f(x)$ follows that $f(x)=0$ a.e. for any $\lambda$. Notice, that for $x\in[0,\infty)$, $1-e^{-x}\in[0,1]$ and if $\lambda\in[0,1]$, then set $Y_\varepsilon=\{x\in[0,\infty):|1-e^{-x}-\lambda|<\varepsilon\}$ has a positive measure for all $\varepsilon>0$. Then consider the sequence $f_n(x)=\dfrac{\chi_{Y_n}}{\|\chi_{Y_n}\|}$, where $Y_n=\{x\in[0,\infty):|1-e^{-x}-\lambda|<\frac{1}{n}\}$. It's obvious that $\|f_n\|=1$, but $\|(T-\lambda I)f_n(x)\|\leq\frac{1}{n}\to0$. Thus, $\lambda\in[0,1]$ -- is points of spectrum. In view of the above, these are points of the continuous spectrum.

In this argument I used a well-known fact (it's very easy to prove, only by definitions): if for a number $\lambda$ there exists a normalized sequence $\{x_n\}$ such that $Tx_n-\lambda x_n\to0$, then $\lambda\in\sigma(A)$.

For all other real $\lambda$, you can easily check that the operator $T-\lambda I$ is invertible and it's inverse operator is bounded on whole space, so these are points of the resolvent set.

Comment: Thanks! A question, why if $\lambda \in [0,1]$ then the set $Y_\epsilon$ has a positive measure?

Comment: In this particular case, you can simply solve the inequality and get an interval whose measure is certainly positive.

Comment: Ok, a little bit difficult but I can overcome in time; the characteristic function in $f_n$ is the restriction of $f$ to the set $Y_\epsilon$ right? This is the kind of passage that makes me freak out with this

Comment: No, $f_n$ it's just a name of sequence. The sequence $f_n$ has nothing to do with function $f$. If you want, label it $g_n$.

Comment: So the condition for beign in the continuous spectrum that you have shown is perfectly equivalent to show that $Ker(\bar{\lambda}-T^*)=\{0\}$, right? I'm trying to connect the pieces, this is another condition for the continous spectrum

Comment: You probably wanted to write $\ker(\bar{\lambda}I-T^*)=\{0\}$? If so, this is not necessary true condition for continuous spectrum. For example, for self-adjoint operator in Hilbert space this condition equivalent to $\ker(\lambda I-T)=\{0\}$, what means only injectivity, but not necessary non-surjectivity of $T-\lambda I$. But if you know that a $\lambda$ is a point in the spectrum of self-adjoint operator in Hilbert space, then this condition really means what you want.

Comment: One more clarification! The result that $\lambda\in[0,1]$  are points of spectrum derive exactly from the condition that $\sigma(T)=\{ \lambda \in C : | \lambda | \leq 1\}$  right?

Comment: It follows from the fact that the set of values of the function $1-e^{-x}$ is $[0,1]$.

Comment: If I wanto to prove that $[0,1]$ (that is $Range(\lambda I - T)$) is dense in $H$, is more or less your passage with $Y_n$ right? Because if I can show that and that $( \lambda I -T)^{-1}$ is not bounded, it's another sufficient condition for the continous spectrum$

Comment: To prove that the operator $(T-\lambda I)^{-1}$ not bounded for $\lambda\in[0,1]$, it's enough to prove that there is a sequence $\{x_n\}$ such that $\|x_n\|=1$ and $(T-\lambda I)(x_n)\to0$. Because, if $(T-\lambda I)^{-1}$ were bounded (i.e. continuous), then $(T-\lambda I)^{-1}(T-\lambda I)(x_n)\to0$, i.e. $x_n\to0$ which is contradiction. Because for self-adjoint operator residual spectrum is empty, we get only continuous spectrum points.