# Point and continuous spectrum of a multiplication operator in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory

Let $M_\alpha f(x) = sin(\frac{x}{\alpha})f(x)$. Compute its spectrum.

My idea is to find the measure of the set $A_\lambda = \left\{x \in \mathbb{R} : sin(\frac{x}{\alpha}) = \lambda\right\}$. If the measure of $A_\lambda$ is zero, then $\lambda$ is not an eigenvalue. So, is it true that in this case the point spectrum is empty? What about the continuous spectrum?

Comment: You're correct that $A_\lambda$ has measure zero (indeed it is countable) and therefore $\lambda$ is not an eigenvalue, so yes, the point spectrum is empty.  For the continuous spectrum: what criteria do you know for a value to be in the continuous spectrum?

Comment: The continuous spectrum consists of the essential values of the function $\sin(x/\alpha)$. In this case, this simply coincides with a set of values. See also this answer https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3631307/spectrum-of-the-operator-t-in-mathcalll2-bbbr-defined-by-tfx/3631487#3631487

Comment: @thing so, in my case the continuous spectrum would be [-1,1], right?